# checking primitive data type for null

Tags: java

I have the primitive variable `notional` of `double` type:

```java
private double notional;
```

Now I have to do a `null` check and throw an `Exception` if it is `null`:

```java
if (item.getNotional() == null) {
    throw new Exception("Rfgygf");
}
```

But this is cannot be the correct approach since primitive types cannot be `null`. Please explain how to perform a proper `null` check on `notional` in Java.

Is there a way to do this with a with `double` or do I need to convert it into `Double`?

Comment: Primitive type cannot be null. [Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/null-for-primitive-data-types)

Comment: @hfkjflhfjgdjdhkd You can set a "per say" `null` value so you know its `null` when its a specific value.... like most comonly used `-1` but this in no way means it is null just saying

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yeah but is there any way to overcome from this now

Comment: So, you have a field of type `double`. Now, you want to check if it is null, but you know that it cannot be null. It simply doesn't make sense. Why should you do this? What do you mean by "if it is coming as null"?

Answer (score 7):

Primitive data types such as `double` and `int` cannot be null. It's like an `int` cannot be `1.1`.

Which means, you don't need to worry about nullity in primitive data types! They are **never** null and thus will not throw `NullPointerException`s. I guess the reason why you have this confusion is that you think a variable without a value must be null. But that is wrong. Consider this class:

```
public class MyClass { int i; }
```

And now you create an object of the class:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Now you print `obj.i`. What will it be? It's not null, it's `0`!

All primitive data types have a *default value*. For instance, The default value of `int` is 0, the default value of `double` is `0.0`, which explains why the above `obj.i` is 0. And what is the default for `char`? It's `'\0'`!

Just remember that primitive data types cannot be `null`.

#### Never

### Never

## Never

Answer (score 1):

A primitive type cannot have a null value. Only reference types can have a null value. When you first declare a double, the value stored inside is a 0.
Basically, objects of type double will always store a value. If you don't specify what that value is, it will be a 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
private double notional;
```

It is not `null`, it is `0.0d`. Primitive values cannot be `null`.

[JLS-4.12.1. Variables of Primitive Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.1) says (in part)

> A variable of a primitive type always holds a primitive value of that exact primitive type.

And `null` is not a primitive value. The explanation can be found at [JLS-4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) which says (in part)

> For type `double`, the default value is positive zero, that is, `0.0d`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have indicated, primitive data types cannot be null.

I suggest you look at the `Optional` class as an alternative to using nulls to represent no value. Java 8 includes `Optional` and there are similar versions in the guava library.