# Convert null to int

Tags: java, arrays, null, int, stack

While working with stacks/queues in pop() or dequeue() operations I had bits of code which went like this:

```
myarray[t--]=null;
```

The implementation was in the form of an array of ints. 
I get an error which goes like " cannot be converted to int". Now I realize this reassigning to null isnt explicitly necessary for this implementation since I'm keeping track of the top of the stack. 
But anyway, how do I overcome this error?

Comment: Use array of wrapper type `Integer`

Comment: The traditional way is to not do anything with "leftover" `int`s. As you say, you're keeping track of the top anyway.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: please leave a criticism along with your vote. I searched for a duplicate so I could close this Question but did not find one.

Answer (score 1):

[Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) such as `int` cannot be null. Use an object instead, the class [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) in this case. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11047276/642706) for more discussion.

Please declare your array `myarray` as follows:

```
int size =10; // size of array
Integer[] myarray=new Integer[size];
```

Now, you can assign as:

```
myarray[t--]=null;
```

Comment: So I take it that using Integer is a prereq for such an assignment? Thanks.

Comment: Yes @Neodymia you may not assign `null` to an array of primitives such as `int`. You need to use wrapper class `Integer` for such scenario.

Comment: @Neodymia No need for an Integer object when assigning a value, such as `myArray[t] = 7 ;`. Java will conveniently create an `Integer` object  from your `int` primitive value. See the [Tutorial on autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).