# JavaFX: Storing null in a SimpleIntegerProperty

Tags: java, javafx, null, primitive

I have a `SimpleIntegerProperty` which should be able to store `null`. However, this is not possible, as written in the JavaDoc of [IntegerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.html):

> Note: setting or binding this property to a `null` value will set the property to "0.0". See `setValue(java.lang.Number)`.

This also applies to other properties, such as `LongProperty`, `FloatProperty`, `DoubleProperty`, and `BooleanProperty` (but not to `StringProperty`, which allows `null`!). Why is this the case? Is there a workaround to store `null` in these properties?

Comment: The primitive wrapper type, `IntegerProperty`, `DoubleProperty`, etc, are intended as exactly that: observable wrappers for primitive types. So `IntegerProperty` is intended to wrap an `int`, which of course cannot take on a `null` value. For convenience, `IntegerProperty` implements `Property<Number>`, so it inherits the `setValue(Number)` method; however it is not intended to be used to set the value to `null` (and as you observed, is documented to set the value to a default of `0`). If you want an observable that can take on `null`, use `ObjectProperty<Integer>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `IntegerProperty.setValue(java.lang.Number)` method is specified in the interfaces [WriteableIntegerValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableIntegerValue.html#setValue-java.lang.Number-) and [WriteableValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableValue.html#setValue-T-). The JavaDoc of [WriteableIntegerValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableIntegerValue.html#setValue-java.lang.Number-), states:

> Note: this method should accept `null` without throwing an exception, setting "0" instead.

If you are looking at the code of the `IntegerPropertyBase` class, you can also see that the value is actually stored as a primitive `int` ([which never can be `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/null-for-primitive-data-types)). This is also specified in the JavaFX API of [SimpleIntegerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html):

> This class provides a full implementation of a Property wrapping a **`int`** value.

**Solution**:
You can simply circumvent that by using a `SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>` instead of a `SimpleIntegerProperty`, as a `SimpleObjectProperty` allows `null` values