# Convert Database Entity from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am currently converting my projects to Kotlin and I have an app with Room database using Java.

My Entity in Java

```
@Entity(tableName = "store")
@Fts4
public class Store {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    private Long identification;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "days_open")
    private int daysOpen;

    public Store(Long identification, @NonNull String name, String location, int daysOpen) {
        this.identification = identification;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.daysOpen = daysOpen
    }

    public Long getIdentification() {
        return identification;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public int getDaysOpen() {
        return daysOpen;
    }
}
```

I convert it this way to Kotlin

```
@Entity(tableName = "store")
@Fts4
data class Store(

    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid") 
    val identification: Long?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    val location: String?

    @ColumnInfo(name = "days_open")
    val daysOpen: Int?
)
```

Now I am having this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

Do we really need to do migration in this? Or I am wrong converting things. I am using Room 2.3.0.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

When I updated the database version, this is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
```

I added this code to my database

```
val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("
        // put changes here
        ")}
}
```

I don't know what to put inside of migrate function. Any idea?

Comment: This is just a guess but with location `String` and `String?` may not convert to the same thing as far as `room` is concerned. And since you most likely want to keep the option open for a null location I think the ! operator might work.    `val location: String!`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. It says Unexpected Token.

Comment: That would be my guess too **if** you were using the wrong `@NonNull`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109367/506796). But there's no such thing as a `!` operator for type nullability. Try using `?` to make it a nullable String.

Comment: Oh, it looks like your `identification` Long field is a nullable Long in Java, so it needs to be `Long?` in Kotlin. Not sure if Room would treat a PrimaryKey as nullable though, even if you didn't specify `@NonNull` for it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am using correct '@NonNull'... import androidx.annotation.NonNull

Comment: @Tenfour04 already did it. Still got error. Is it probably because of Fts4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got the solution.

The problem is my `int` in Java Entity is different w/ `Int` in Kotlin. Thus, I need to update my schema by Migration. My solution is referenced
[here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929).

Comment: Can you post how you fix it? I cannot see how in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message seems to be quite clear. you need to update the version of your room database.
Go to the class that extends `RoomDatabase` and increment the value of `version` attribute in `@Database` annotation.

```
@Database(entities = [A::class, B::class], version = 2)
abstract class YourRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase()
```

Comment: Already done this, it says I need to add the addMigration(Migration ...). But I don't know what to put here because I didn't change my schema, I just convert the language that I used. Any idea to put in AddMigration()?

Comment: First update your question with exact error you are getting