# Can't set boolean field explicitly to null

Tags: java, boolean

I have this:

```
  public static class RaceParam {

    boolean keep = null; // does not compile

  }
```

that won't compile because you can't assign null to a primitive. So that begs the question, what value does keep get when we do this:

```
  public static class RaceParam {

    boolean keep;

  }
```

does it default to false or true? Seems dangerous to default to something.

Comment: User wrapper class if you want to set null. use Boolean instead of boolean.

Comment: Yes, it's (potentially) dangerous to rely on the default value of a primitive.  You should assign an explicit default value if possible.  Regarding the `null` problem, you may use a `Boolean` field instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure but what is the default value of a primitive boolean? :)

Comment: Disagree it's "dangerous" to rely on default values.  Default values in Java are well defined.  They're zero for all primitives except `boolean`, which is `false`.  For references it's `null`.

Comment: @MrCholo It's `false`.

Comment: @markspace I agree, but from a business logic point of view, sometimes it can be safer to always explicitly assign some default value.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann The [currently linked original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11047276/642706) of this duplicate seems to be different than the one you quoted. This Question here is indeed a duplicate of the currently linked original.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann The *only* place I have seen the phrase “What is the default of bool?” is in your comments. I’ve no idea where you you got that from. I suspected someone somewhere changed something, hence my comment to you as a heads-up about current conditions. Both this Question and it’s linked original ask why can’t we assign null to a Boolean primitive.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ah, okay, I think I got you now. 1. Sorry, bool is a typo should have been boolean. 2. OP states as a *fact* that you cannot assign null, he seems to know that and he does not ask that. Instead OP asks: "So that begs the question, what value does keep get when we do this:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `boolean` defaults to `false`

`boolean` is a primitive and can only hold the values *true* or *false*. The default value is *false*.

```
boolean keep;  // Defaults to `false`.
```

Use the wrapper class `Boolean` if you want to assign a null value. For eg :

```
Boolean keep = null;
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question tho, I am wondering what the default value is for the keep field if it's not explicitly assigned to null..and the reasoning behind it if possible.

Comment: Updated the answer. Default value is false.

Comment: @MrCholo To be fair, you didn't ask what happens to a `boolean` field that does not get assigned anything too.

Comment: @Jai MrCholo is always right!

Answer (score 3):

From [jls 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.

Answer (score -1):

The default value of `Boolean` keep is null, just like any other object. You have to explicitly initialize it.

Comment: The Question is about `boolean` the primitive, not `Boolean` the class.