# How to Read "NULL" value for a NUMBER column from Oracle using MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis

I'm trying to read NULL value and 0 value from a NUMBER column from a table but for both I'm getting the value as 0.

How to read NULL value and 0 whenever needed.

**Mapper.xml:**

```
<select id="callGetDRHoldingsAdmin" parameterType="map" resultType="com.project.employee">
    SELECT 
        EMP_NUM AS empNum,
        EMP_SAL AS empSal,
        EMP_NAME AS empName
    FROM EMP_TABLE
</select>
```

**Employee POJO**

```
class Employee {
    private double empSal,
    private int empNum,
    private String empName
}
```

**EMP_TABLE:**

```
EMP_NAME : VARCHAR2(30)
EMP_SAL  : NUMBER
EMP_NUM  : NUMBER
```

Comment: Could it be because you are using scalar types for `empSal` and `empNum` in your `Employee` class? That is, they will default to `0.0` and `0` respectively if there's nothing assigned to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double` and `int` are primitive types in java. The variables of these types [can't hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/why-cant-primitive-data-types-be-null-in-java) `null`.

Use corresponding wrapper type which can store `null`:

```
class Employee {
    private Double empSal,
    private Integer empNum,
    private String empName
}
```