# Is the Java null type a subtype of all primitive types?

Tags: java, types, language-lawyer, jls, subtyping

The Java Language Specification 20, Section [4.10. Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) states that

> The *subtypes* of a type T are all types U such that T is a supertype of U, and the null type. We write T `<:` S to indicate that that the subtype relation holds between types T and S.

Does this mean, that the null type is a subtype of all primitive types? And if yes, are there any practical consequences?

I'm writing a library to parse and analyze java code, so should I treat `null` as a subtype of, say, `int`? Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: No. `null` is a reference type. Primitives cannot have reference types.  See answers to  [Why can't primitive data types be "null" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/why-cant-primitive-data-types-be-null-in-java).  An example: If you have a method call, say signature is `foo (int bar, double bat)`, you cannot call `foo (null, 3.14159)`. There is no place you can use `null` in place of a primitive.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer This is a JLS question. The quoted sentences do not restrict T to class and interface types; they're in the section that applies to all types: primitives, objects, and arrays alike. I, too, am curious how to reconcile the quoted bit with the fact that primitives can't be null.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I don't think so. Go back 9 sections to [4.1. The Kinds of Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), which says there are two kinds of types and then adds a third (special) null type.

Comment: subtype or rahter "supertype"?  Anyway, *no*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, I see that. Section 4.1 defines what the null type is. What I find notable is that 4.10 doesn't say "The subtypes of a *reference* type T...". It places no restrictions on T, implying that T can be a reference type, primitive type, or null type.

Comment: I'm sure there's an answer, but I just want to point out that this JLS citation is neither asked about in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047276/why-cant-primitive-data-types-be-null-in-java) nor mentioned in any of the answers, so I disagree with marking it a duplicate of such.

Comment: I wonder if it's a spec defect. In section 4.10.2 it says, "The direct supertypes of the null type are all reference types other than the null type itself." That is a better match for what all of us believe to be the case.

Comment: *"I'm writing a library to parse and analyze java code, so should I treat `null` as a subtype of, say, `int`? Or does it not matter at all?"*  This last paragraph of the O/P question makes it a practical question, not just a JLS question.

Comment: The term "Subtype" is defined through the "Supertype". Now, the question boils down to showing if it is possible for a primitive type to be a supertype of null? The answer is no, according to 4.10.2: The direct supertypes of the null type are all reference types other than the null type itself. Hence, null can't be a subtype of primitive types either. We have to use the definition of supertype to reason about subtypes, not vice versa.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov That's how it *should* be. However, the subtype definition includes the phrase "and the null type", which as I read it makes the definitions asymmetrical, and inconsistent with the sentence you quoted from 4.10.2.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, gave it a thought. Perhaps "and null" part indeed makes statements contradict for primitive types. In fact, if we omit it, the conclusion that the null type is a subtype for all reference types can be inferred from 4.10.2 and the definition of the subtype.

Comment: What if we say “yes”? I couldn’t find any place in the JLS where this had an impact. It was even hard to find a place where the subtype relationships specified in §4.10.1 have an impact and the only place I eventually found is not affected by this question.